# Script to remove older files from various directories

Tags: bash

I want to remove files(whose name contains "extract") older than 7 days from various directories in a particular path.
If I run the script without any argument the script should be able to delete the files from all the directories inside that particular path.
If I run the script using any arguments , then the script should not delete files from those specific directories.

Example :-

Path - /languages/analytics

Let's assume directory "analytics" contains 10 dirctories like c,java,javascript,python,shell,golang,scala,ruby,react,angular.This directory also contains few files along with these 10 directories.

Scenario1 - I want to remove the files older than 7 days from all the 10 directories.

Scenario2 - I want to remove the files older than 7 days from all directories except angular.

Scenario3 - I want to remove the files older than 7 days from all directories except ruby,react,shell.

So basically whatever arguments I pass , the script should not delete files from those particular directories.The number of arguments may vary as per requirement.And if I run without arguments, then the script should delete older files from all the directories in that path.The number of directories may vary as well.

Here is what I have written so far ...

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /languages/analytics
for f in *; do
    if [ -d "$f" ] && [[ "$f" != $1 ]]; then
        find /languages/analytics/"$f" -mtime +7 -name '*extract*' -exec rm -f {} \;        
    fi
done
```

The above script works fine when I run it without arguments.
It runs fine when I pass 1 argument.

sh scriptname -> successfully deletes files from all directories in /languages/analytics path.

sh scriptname ruby -> successfully delete files from all directories except ruby.

Can you please advise how to enhance this script to take as many arguments as possible and the script should not delete files from those particular directories which are passed in the argument ?

Comment: does `sh scriptname ruby` should exclude `/languages/analytics/ruby/` only? or for example `/languages/analytics/test/ruby/` also?

Comment: Btw: `find` can exclude directories using `-prune`, so no need for that `for` and `if`. A single `find` command should be sufficient.

Comment: @Fravadona "sh scriptname ruby" -> This should exclude /languages/analytics/ruby/ only.I'm able to achieve this with my above script.
Similarly "sh scriptname ruby golang" -> This should exclude /languages/analytics/ruby/ and /languages/analytics/golang/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

for dir in /languages/analytics/*/; do
    for arg; do [[ $dir == */"$arg"/ ]] && continue 2; done
    find "$dir" -mtime +7 -name '*extract*' -exec rm -f {} \;
done
```

- `for arg; do` loops over the positional arguments (`$1`, `$2`, ...)
- `continue 2` skips to the next iteration of the outer (`for dir ...`) loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

args=("${@}")

mainpath=./languages/analytics
readarray -t datafolders < <(find "$mainpath" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -print0|xargs -0 -I {} basename {})

for subfolder in "${args[@]}"; do
  for i in "${!datafolders[@]}"; do
    if [[ ${datafolders[i]} = "$subfolder" ]]; then
      unset 'datafolders[i]'
    fi
  done
done

datafolders=( "${datafolders[@]/#/$mainpath/}" )

declare -p datafolders


# delete command for multiple folders 
# find "${datafolders[@]}" -type f -mtime +7 -name '*extract*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

---

For my test i used `"./languages/analytics"`

**Scenario 1** all directories

```
$ ./script.sh
declare -a datafolders=([0]="./languages/analytics/ruby" [1]="./languages/analytics/react" [2]="./languages/analytics/scala" [3]="./languages/analytics/java" [4]="./languages/analytics/angular" [5]="./languages/analytics/javascript" [6]="./languages/analytics/python" [7]="./languages/analytics/shell" [8]="./languages/analytics/golang" [9]="./languages/analytics/c")
```

**Scenario 2** except angular

```
$ ./script.sh angular
declare -a datafolders=([0]="./languages/analytics/ruby" [1]="./languages/analytics/react" [2]="./languages/analytics/scala" [3]="./languages/analytics/java" [4]="./languages/analytics/javascript" [5]="./languages/analytics/python" [6]="./languages/analytics/shell" [7]="./languages/analytics/golang" [8]="./languages/analytics/c")
```

**Scenario 3** except ruby react shell

```
$ ./script.sh execpt ruby react shell
declare -a datafolders=([0]="./languages/analytics/scala" [1]="./languages/analytics/java" [2]="./languages/analytics/angular" [3]="./languages/analytics/javascript" [4]="./languages/analytics/python" [5]="./languages/analytics/golang" [6]="./languages/analytics/c")
```